# Detect when entry is focused?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm making a custom control of an entry. I have my custom view with the logic of the control and a MainPage and a ViewModel where I edit the visual part of the control.

I want to detect when I focus in the entry and when I focus the entry, do something. I tried this but it don't work.

Frame.xaml (Custom control):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="CustomControl.Frame"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControl"
    x:Name="CustomView">
    <ContentView.Content>

        <StackLayout>

            <!--  This is what I want to change  -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Frame
                    Margin="0,0,0,2"
                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=FrameColor}"
                    BorderColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=BorderColor}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=CornerRadius}"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Clicked="Open"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=LeftSideIcon}" />

                        <Entry
                            x:Name="EntryControl"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,30,0"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Keyboard="Chat"
                            Placeholder="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=Placeholder}"
                            Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                            TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EntryTextColor}" />

                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="5"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMsgCommand}"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMessageIcon}" />


                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
                <ImageButton
                    Margin="0,0,5,2"
                    Padding="15,0,10,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendBtnColor}"
                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendMsgCommand}"
                    CornerRadius="30"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=RightSideIcon}"
                    WidthRequest="45" />
            </StackLayout>
            <!--  ================================  -->

            <Frame
                x:Name="frameemojis"
                Margin="0,-8,0,0"
                IsVisible="false">
                <CollectionView
                    Margin="-10,-15,-10,-10"
                    HeightRequest="270"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiItemSource}"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">

                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="5" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ImageButton
                                Padding="5"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiTappedCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding EmojiMethodCommand}"
                                HeightRequest="44"
                                Source="{Binding EmojiSource}"
                                WidthRequest="44" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                </CollectionView>
            </Frame>
            <!--  ==============  -->

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentView.Content>


</ContentView>
```

Frame.xaml.cs (custom control):

```
 public partial class Frame : ContentView
{


    //===============Frame Color=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty FrameColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("FrameColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Frame));

    public Color FrameColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(FrameColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FrameColorProperty, value); }
    }

    //===============SendBtn Color=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty SendBtnColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SendBtnColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Frame));

    public Color SendBtnColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SendBtnColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SendBtnColorProperty, value); }
    }


    //===============Border Color=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("BorderColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Frame));

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
    }
    //===============Corner radius=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("CornerRadius", typeof(int), typeof(Frame));

    public int CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    //===============Left side Icon=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty LeftSideIconProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("LeftSideIcon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Frame));

    public ImageSource LeftSideIcon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(LeftSideIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LeftSideIconProperty, value); }
    }
    //===============Placeholder=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Placeholder", typeof(string), typeof(Frame));

    public string Placeholder
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
    }


    //===============Entry text Color=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTextColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("EntryTextColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Frame));

    public Color EntryTextColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(EntryTextColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EntryTextColorProperty, value); }
    }

    //===============Delete message command=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty DeleteMsgCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("DeleteMsgCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Frame));

    public ICommand DeleteMsgCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DeleteMsgCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeleteMsgCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    //===============Delete Message Icon=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty DeleteMessageIconProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("DeleteMessageIcon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Frame));

    public ImageSource DeleteMessageIcon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(DeleteMessageIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeleteMessageIconProperty, value); }
    }


    //===============Send message command=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty SendMsgCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SendMsgCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Frame));

    public ICommand SendMsgCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SendMsgCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SendMsgCommandProperty, value); }
    }



    //===============Right side icon=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty RightSideIconProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("RightSideIcon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Frame));

    public ImageSource RightSideIcon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(RightSideIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightSideIconProperty, value); }
    }


    //===============Item Source==========================
    public static readonly BindableProperty EmojiItemSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("EmojiItemSource", typeof(IList), typeof(Frame));

    public IList EmojiItemSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(EmojiItemSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmojiItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    //===============EmojiTap command=====================
    public static readonly BindableProperty EmojiTappedCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("EmojiTappedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Frame));

    public ICommand EmojiTappedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(EmojiTappedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmojiTappedCommandProperty, value); }
    }




    public ICommand FocusedCommand { get; set; }


    bool state = true;
    void Open(object o, System.EventArgs e)
    {


        if (state)
        {
            state = false;
            frameemojis.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = true;
            frameemojis.IsVisible = false;
        }

    }


    public Frame()
    {

     

        EntryControl.Focused += (s, a) => {


            if (!state)
            {
                state = true;
                frameemojis.IsVisible = false;
            }
        };

       InitializeComponent();
    } 
    
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App24.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:fav="clr-namespace:CustomControl;assembly=CustomControl">


    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>

                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#686A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="#806A2234"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    WidthRequest="100">
                    <Label Text="{Binding RecievedMessage}" />

                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>




        <StackLayout
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

            <fav:Frame
                x:Name="entrycontrol"
                BorderColor="{Binding EntryBorderColor}"
                CornerRadius="{Binding EntryRadius}"
                DeleteMessageIcon="crossblack.png"
                DeleteMsgCommand="{Binding DeleteMsgCommand}"
                EmojiItemSource="{Binding EmojiList}"
                EmojiTappedCommand="{Binding EmojiTappedCommand}"
                EntryTextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                FrameColor="{Binding EntryBGColor}"
                LeftSideIcon="icon.png"
                Placeholder="Escribame"
                RightSideIcon="send.png"
                SendBtnColor="{Binding SendBtnColor}"
                SendMsgCommand="{Binding SendMsgCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>



    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use the Entry's Focused event

Comment: I tried it too and didnt work. How must I implement it? Maybe I did it wrong

Comment: I test with the codes below,it could fire the Fouces event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `Focused` event

```
InitializeComponent();

EntryControl.Focused += (s,a) => {

  if (!state) {
    state = true;
    frameemojis.IsVisible = false;
  }
};
```

Comment: It did't work, I edited my post with my code trying this. I don't know why is not working

Comment: first, don't name a custom control the same thing as a standard UI element.  That's incredibly confusing.  Second, you need to call `InitializeComponent` **before** you can refer to a XAML element by its name.

Comment: I edited my code and I called InitializeComponent  before and still not working. I dont know what is happening

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you used the debugger to check if the Focused event is being fired?

Comment: I tried the lines you posted. Also, to check if the event is being fired, I write Debugger.Break(); when focused and nothing happened